# Adding dots after section numbers in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, numbering, customize

I am working with the book class and already have arranged things so that the section and chapter numbering in the actual text looks ok to me.

However, in my setting, I don't know how to add dots behind the section numbers in the table of contents. (I already have the dots in the actual titles of the text.)

Here is the relevant code of my current setting:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}

% format toc
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\l@section}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1cm}{0.4cm}}
\makeatother


% format section and chapter numbers (applies in text and toc)
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}


% format titles in text
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\Large\bfseries}{\thesection.}{0.2cm}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{1cm}{0.3cm}


% format header for pages with text
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\thepage}
```

For the table of contents, this code produces something like

```
I  Chapter                                          3
   1 Section one .................................. 4
   2 Section two .................................. 5
```

But I want

```
I  Chapter                                          3
   1. Section one ................................. 4
   2. Section two ................................. 5
```

with a dot behind the section the numbers.

I already tried the command `\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}` but it didn't work for me.

Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: `\l@section`is the command that calls `\cftsecaftersnum` ordinarily, but you've redefined it so it doesn't. Remove that first `\renewcommand` and your `\renewcommand` for `\cftsecaftersnum` would work. What were you trying to achieve with that first redefinition? tocloft probably offers a different way of achieving the same thing.

Comment: @frabjous thanks for the explanation. I use the ```\renewcommand{\l@section}``` to change the spacing between the section numbers and the section titles in the table of contents (i.e. make the space smaller). This is something I don't want to omit. So, is it not possible to use ```\renewcommand{\l@section}``` for changing the spacing as I did and at the same time, introducing the dots behind the section numbers? Is there an alternative way I could change the spacing?

Comment: It just leaves a fairly wide space for the section number to make sure there's enough room if you go into double digits. If you're never going to go into double digits, you could just reduce the width reserved for the number: `\renewcommand{\cftsecnumwidth}{1.5em}`; adjust to taste. (Or I suppose you could right align the number in the space alloted.)

Comment: @frabjous, thanks! Works great!